# Web Api - How to return a dynamic object with 201 status code

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-web-api2, expandoobject

I'm trying to return the recently added entity Id in a Web Api action method as a JSON. Example:

```
{ bookId = 666 }
```

The Controller Action code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost, Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage Add(dynamic inputs)
{
    int bookId = bookService.Add(userId, title);

    dynamic book = new ExpandoObject();
    book.bookId = bookId

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        Content = new ObjectContent<dynamic>(book,
            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true
            })
    };
}
```

The problem here is to accomplish it returning a dynamic content (without Dto) and returning the HttpStatusCode.Created (201 http status).

Now I have the next error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"No se espera el tipo 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' ...

if I change the `new ObjectContent<dynamic>` by `new ObjectContent<ExpandoObject>` I get the correct 201 status header response, but the JSON result is as as follows:

```
[{"Key":"bookId","Value":666}]
```

So, is it possible to return { bookId: 666} using dynamics (not Dtos) setting the header status code to 201 (Created)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you see is correct because a `dynamic` / `ExpandoObject` is effectively just a wrapper around a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

If you want it to be serialized as an object then you should use an [anonymous object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) instead of an `ExpandoObject` e.g.

```
int bookId = bookService.Add(userId, title);

var book = new { bookId = bookId };

return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<object>(book,
        new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
        {
            UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true
        })
};
```

If `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` doesn't support anonymous objects then you could try using the default serializer

```
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, book);
```

Comment: this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, book); works like a charm. Thank you!